# Magento showing wrong customer ip

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a US based website when customer placed order, in their order "Placed from IP" showing my ip in each order also, I have few custom module for tracking order and user activity in these modules ip is showing mine. it's strange.I am not found the issue.Also when i'm printing ip from root folder then it's working fine.

My module code :

```
function getUserIP()
    {
        $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
        {
            $ip = $client;
        }
        elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
        {
            $ip = $forward;
        }
        else
        {
            $ip = $remote;
        }
        return $ip;
    }
```

But my concern is Magento default `sales/order` code should be run fine.

Comment: what code are you using to get client ip?

Comment: In sales order mageto's default code working

Comment: Please refer the below link.Best of Luck... https://go.eway.io/s/article/Magento-is-using-the-wrong-customer-IP-address

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157507)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the above my issue.

There was a code placed in index.php

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '202.164.34.112'){
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
}
```

I have commented this piece of code and all the thing are working fine now.